# What is the right way to write a spring.io REST controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm very new to spring and trying to get a webapp up and running. I can serve the static material, but am having a hard time getting a connection to a database. I'm definitely doing something and perhaps several things wrong.

My code

```
package com.parrit;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.parrit.models.Workspace;
import com.parrit.models.WorkspaceRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/workspace")
public class WorkspaceController {

    private final WorkspaceRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public WorkspaceController(WorkspaceRepository repository) {
        Assert.notNull(repository, "Repository must not be null");
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    void save( @RequestBody String workspaceHTML) {
        Workspace ws = new Workspace();
        ws.setHTML(workspaceHTML);
        repository.save(ws);
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a controller that saves a new repository object anytime someone goes to the save route. What am I doing wrong/where can I go to learn what I am doing wrong.

Error message that I'm getting
Here's an example :

```
Error creating bean with name 'workspaceController' defined in file [PROJECT_ROOT/target/classes/com/parrit/WorkspaceController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.parrit.WorkspaceController]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.parrit.WorkspaceController.<init>()
```

I have that class, and I think that I have that class in the bean search paths but I really am not super sure.

Here is that class in case it's something there

```
package com.parrit.models;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface WorkspaceRepository extends JpaRepository<Workspace, Long> {

}
```

Comment: What sort of error messages are you seeing?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax. The error messages I'm getting are saying that there is no bean 'WorkspaceController'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks that Spring require a non-argument constructor.... try to move the @Autowired annotation from the constructor to the attribute and double check that WorkspaceRepository is a Spring bean.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/workspace")
public class WorkspaceController {

    @Autowired
    private WorkspaceRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    void save( @RequestBody String workspaceHTML) {
        Workspace ws = new Workspace();
        ws.setHTML(workspaceHTML);
        repository.save(ws);
    }
}
```

And check this thread: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/97753-how-to-autowire-a-bean-without-default-constructor

**Update:**

Set up Spring to create proxy instances for those JPA Repo interfaces. 
Either via JavaConfig:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories
class Config {}
```

or via XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa     http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

   <jpa:repositories base-package="com.parrit.models"/>

</beans>
```

see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods

Comment: How do I double-check that WorkspaceRepository is a Spring bean?

Comment: See the update section: check that spring have the JPA repositories enables or configured, so the Auto wired annotation find a bean (when annotated the controller attribute spring will asign automatically the bean if exits or throw an exception if can't find it)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is clearly stated in the Spring error message:
`Failed to instantiate [com.parrit.WorkspaceController]: No default constructor found;`

This means Spring expects your `WorkspaceController` object to define a no-arg constructor, but it does not.

Comment: okay, that did seem to move the error along. Unfortunately now it's saying that the WorkspaceRepository might not be initialized. How would I get an instance of the WorkspaceRepository into this context?

Comment: @Pinwheeler don't ask follow-up questions in comments, if it's a new issue post a new question.